# Breaking Out Of A Loop Using A Method In Java

Tags: java, loops, methods, break, continue

I am trying to use a method to double check before a user exits a while loop in my program.

```
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void ays() {
    System.out.println("Are you sure?");
    String ays = input.nextLine();
    if (ays.equals("Yes")) {
       break; 
    } else {
       continue;
    }
}
```

Upon running the program, I get the error `break outside switch or loop`, and `continue outside switch or loop`. Is there any way to achieve my goal here?

Comment: `break` can only be used inside a loop as it breaks the loop and comes directly to the first statement outside the loop. `continue` takes the control at the start of the loop again discarding all other statements below the `continue` statement.

Comment: break can be used to break out of switch statement http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html or a loop in java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

You can refer to the posted oracle java tutorial links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are invoking `ays()` inside a while loop. Let the return type of `ays()` be `boolean` and let it `return` either `true` or `false`. Invoke `ays()` from inside the `while` loop and based on the value returned by `ays()`, you `continue` or `break` out of the loop.

```
while (true) { 
    //Do Something 
    if (ays()) { 
        continue(); 
    } else { 
        break(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree. Could also call `System.exit(0);` to terminate the JVM immediately.